# how do i create a two list from a list inside of an array?

Tags: python

So I have a following code:

```
thing = [   ['Promotion not applied', 'Buy1, get 1 for FOR $4.50', '(', 'details', ')'],      [], ['Promotions Applied:', 'BUY 1, GET 1 FOR $4.50', '(', 'details', ')']   ]
```

so as it loops through a list and I want to create two new lists for promo_applied and promo_not applied:

so the return would be:

```
 promo_applied=["promotions applied", 'Buy1, get 1 for FOR $4.50']
 promo_not_applied = ["promotion not applied", 'Buy1, get 1 for FOR $4.50']
```

Comment: And? What's the issue? You already have those two lists (plus some other stuff), so what 's your actual question? Do you know how to access list elements? As an aside, this feels very [XY-ish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/214517) to me--where are these lists coming from?

Comment: Does the `thing` list always contain 3 elements? Is there more than one possible occurrence of lists starting with `'Promotion not applied'` or `'Promotion applied'` in `thing`?

Comment: I think you should step back and design your program in more detail. In particular, you should learn about classes and objects which you can use to represent each promotion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
thing = [   ['Promotion not applied', 'Buy1, get 1 for FOR $4.50', '(', 'details', ')'],      [], ['Promotions Applied:', 'BUY 1, GET 1 FOR $4.50', '(', 'details', ')']   ]

promo_applied, _, promo_not_applied = map(lambda s:s[:2], thing)
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
thing = [['Promotion not applied', 'Buy1, get 1 for FOR $4.50', '(', 'details', ')'],[],['Promotions Applied:', 'BUY 1, GET 1 FOR $4.50', '(', 'details', ')']]

promo_applied = [_[:2] for _ in thing if 'Promotions Applied:' in _]
promo_not_applied = [_[:2] for _ in thing if 'Promotion not applied' in _]
```